# How filter a word starting with @ form a string in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, filter, ionic2, startswith

I want to filter a @word form a search string. A search string could be `milk @company`. From that string I would use 'milk' as searchTerm and I need '@company' as another search param. So I can do the following: `domain.com/?searchTerm=Milk&Producer=company` with an http request.

in my template:

```
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (ionInput)="searchResults(searchTerm)" [placeholder]="search" ></ion-searchbar>
```

the searchResult function:

```
searchResults() {
    let searchterm = this.searchTerm;
    let producer = // how filter @word? from this.searchTerm string

    this.searchProduct(searchTerm, producer).then(
        data => {
            console.log('data')
        }
    );
}
```

the call to the api provider:

```
   public searchProduct(product,producer){
        var sendUrl = `http://example.com/?searchTerm=${product}$producer=${producer}`;
        this.http.get( sendUrl, { headers: new Headers(HEADER.default) })
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(data => {
                resolve(data);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Is it just one `@word` or it can be `n @word`?

Comment: an @word, could be anything, just starting with an @

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the string split method and use the ‘@‘ as the separator character

```
const searchWords = this.searchTerm.split(‘@‘)
```

This should give you an array with the words.